# magic file: Printing a 3-byte big endian value?

Tags: file, file-format

I'm trying to create a magic database file for the UNIX tool "file" for a specific file format. I have read the whole manual (`man magic` and `man file`) but did not find a way to output a 24-bit big endian integer. I've only found 8 bit (byte), 16 bit (beshort), 32 bit (belong) and 64 bit (bequad).

Is there a way to print a 24-bit (3-byte) big-endian integer from a file with a specific "magic file command"?

Comment: Just calculate the three bytes and put them into a file in appropriate order as 1-byte integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "put them into a file"? I do not have an own program, but I'm writing a "magic" file for the unix tool "file" ( http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic ). "file" uses a magic file to identify file types. I can tell the tool "if a file starts with ABCD, print a line 'ABCD-file' and then print the 'long' value found at offset 4.". But what I want is printing 24 bits, and I can not "calculate" like "Multiply 0x01 with 65536 and 0x02 with 256 and add those three value".

Comment: I'm lost now. Are you trying to *read* a 3-byte integer from a file or *write* it to a file? Your question and your comment seem to indicate opposite actions to me (but that's possibly due to my weak English). What is a 'tool' you use? Do you need to 'print' a value as binary-coded or as a human-readable ASCII string?....

Comment: ....Does your 'tool' offer binary-to-ASCII conversion or you need to do it yourself somehow? Can you program some calculations in the tool? Is it interactive...? script-driven...? configurable batch processor...? Oh, and please add necessary details into your question (use the 'edit' link) instead of comments.

Comment: I'm trying to create a definition file (aka "magic file") for the unix tool "file". "file" is a tool that identifies a files type. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/file for details. That Unix tool "file" has a database file, called "magic file", which contains all the information about all the file types. Like "if a file starts with 'PK', it's a ZIP archive". I can now run the tool with "file ./some-archive.zip" and it tells me that "some-archive.zip" is a ZIP file. I now want to write such a "magic" database for an own file format and I want "file" to output a three-byte-value from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have just found out a way to read a three-byte value with `file`:

Instead of ">0x04 belong x %d" (which prints a 4-byte int from offset 0x04) I use the command ">0x03&0x00ffffff belong x %d" which masks out the first byte and so reads my three-byte value from 0x04.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to write a `magic` rule for a U*x [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) tool. Well, according to the [`magic`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) description, you can't — `magic` format can't describe 3-byte data, so `file` can not read it (and it has no means to combine a 1-byte and 2-byte fields). :-(

BTW, I also could not find a rule to *print out* the magic value found in a file — it's only used internally to decide which message (file type description) should be printed, but is not included into the message.

Comment: To include a value in the output just enter a format string like "%s" (for strings) or "%d" (for numbers) in the output message. Too bad there is no way to use a three-byte value. Is there no "known" file format that uses such a value and is identified by "file"? (Probably not, most developers would just use "int" ...)